# Problems when using "New Windows Terminal" to ssh into non-UTF codepage servers

Tags: wsl2, windows-terminal

I'm using Windows 11 with "New Windows Terminal" (default and "main" application in Windows 11 for working with console, not old `cmd.exe` nor newer `PowerShell.exe`). It has UTF-8 support out of the box and could show non-latin characters, emodji and so on, if they are coming in UTF-8 codepage.

In that terminal I run default Ubuntu wsl profile. From that wsl Ubuntu command line I `ssh` to remote non-Windows servers.

If server uses UTF-8 codepage, all looks fine. But if server uses "classic" non-UTF codepage, I can't see non-latin characters in terminal. Left part of attached image shows the problem.

[image: windows terminal on the left, putty on the right]

For example I have an old FreeBSD server, which does not support UTF-8 in console out of the box (and there is no reason to implement it - this server is kind of heritage which works for decades).

If I use `putty` to ssh this server - I just set up right codepage in Window -> Translation -> Character set -> Remote character set menu (usually `KOI8-R` or `Win1251 (Cyrillic)` is right choice for servers set up to use Cyrillic).

How to set up the same behavior in "New Windows Terminal"? It has dozens of settings, but I can't find anything about codepage.

Or maybe I should use some special `ssh` (not terminal) settings on Windows-side to convert remote server output on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `luit` (or possibly `screen`) as an intermediate layer for codepage conversion.

For reference, the "old Windows Terminal" was generally called "Windows console" and later known as "Conhost". It is not part of Cmd/PowerShell.

> For example I have an old FreeBSD server, which does not support UTF-8 in console out of the box

It doesn't need to – SSH does not involve the remote system's console in any way (the output doesn't go through syscons); all it needs is for the programs to *output* UTF-8 encoded data. A FreeBSD installation from 2008, for example, would already be UTF-8 capable in that sense.

> How to set up the same behavior in "New Windows Terminal"? It has dozens of settings, but I can't find anything about codepage.

Windows Terminal doesn't seem to have such a setting, it relies on the underlying console system to perform translation (it still shares the core of this code with Conhost). Open a regular PowerShell or Cmd tab, then test what happens if you run `chcp 878` before entering WSL from the same tab.

Codepages in Windows console are in general a bit weird, as the underlying system is based on UTF-16 but has two APIs, one to write "OEM codepage" text and another to write UTF-16 text. Traditionally, the "OEM codepage" was set to something like 437 or 775 (roughly the MS-DOS equivalent of whichever 'ANSI' codepage the system was set to), although Windows Terminal nowadays sets it to 65001 indicating that it wants UTF-8. In theory, if you do `chcp 878`, this would make the console work with KOI8-R.

So because Conhost worked either with UTF-16 or OEM codepages for so long, there is actually another translation layer within Win32-OpenSSH – the version of `ssh.exe` that comes with Windows *always* sets the console codepage to 65001 while it runs, and assumes that the output from the SSH server will be UTF-8. This does not affect the Linux `ssh` command that you have in WSL... but I have a strong suspicion that the `wsl.exe` command that you use to enter the whole Ubuntu environment might do the same – it might be always forcing the console to UTF-8, or even translating to UTF-16.

Comment: Run `cmd.exe`, then `chcp 878 ` - returns "Указана недопустимая кодовая страница" ("invalid codepage specified" in Russian). Run `cmd.exe`, then `chcp 1251` - returns "Текущая кодовая страница: 1251" ("current codepage is 1251" in Russian), then `bash` to launch wsl, then `ssh` to remote server - encoding problem persists. Doing same things in `PowerShell.exe` - result is the same. Run wsl, then `screen` without params or `screen -U`, then `ssh` from screen - encoding problem persists.

Comment: `luit -encoding "KOI8-R" ssh remote-host` is the solution. Thank you!