# How to change codepage for WSL console?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, console, code-page

I've read [Problems when using "New Windows Terminal" to ssh into non-UTF codepage servers](https://superuser.com/q/1793353/52492) where an answer suggests using LUIT or maybe Screen. But I am wondering if there is a different answer for the WSL console than for SSH

I am using Oracle Linux 8.5 under WSL on Windows 10.

I have a legacy Linux application that emits text encoded as CP437. It can't be configured to emit UTF-8.

This obviously doesn't display correctly as the WSL Console is understandably set for UTF-8 (code page 65001)

[image: WSL console window properties showing code page 65001]

The "Current Code Page" value here is 65001 but there is no obvious way to set it either temporarily or permanently.

---

I tried opening a command prompt and using `chcp cp437` before invoking `wsl` but this didn't make any difference

[image: screenshot of session with chsp then wsl and test]

Between the >< is some 0xbf characters that I edited in using vim and can see in `hexdump -C`

I'd prefer not to make registry changes or affect my whole Windows environment.

Oracle Linux 8 is derived from Red Hat 8 and has deprecated `screen`. Its package installer `yum` doesn't find `luit` which exhausts my ideas so far for translating CP437 output to UTF-8 inside Linux.

I've tried Windows Terminal (invoked as `terminal` from the desktop search bar, but this doesn't seem to give me any options regarding code pages / encodings.

[image: Windows Terminal running a test]

Note: the white on green border is drawn using ANSI commands, not using the CP437 box-draw characters which I am trying to get working.

---

Can it be done?

Comment: That screenshot appears to be of command prompt not Windows Terminal. Have you tried Windows Terminal? [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8#:~:text=To%20change%20the%20codepage%20for%20the%20console%20only%2C,Processor%5CAutorun%5D%203%20Change%20the%20value%20to%20%40chcp%2065001%3Enul) is how you do it for command prompt

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks, So far exploring those hasn't yielded a solution. (question amended with findings so far)

Comment: UTF-8 has become the encoding of choice for Unix for many years, so a non-UTF-8 encoding on Linux is a fairly edge case by modern standards.

Comment: @mcendu, thanks. I am working with a legacy application that can't really handle multi-byte encodings. It has some *very* rudimentary support for Unicode/UTF-8 data but that doesn't extend to the user interface elements.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an answer to my exact question but I have found a couple of usable workarounds.

### SSHD + PuTTY

Initially, the only workaround I found was starting `sshd` and using Putty.

On Oracle 8.5 Linux in WSL I ran `sudo ssh-keygen -A` then `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd`. Then ran the Putty terminal-emulator, connected to localhost:22 (SSH protocol) and set Putty's translation to CP437 in Settings, Window, Translation.

---

### LUIT

Eventually I decided to make a more determined effort to use LUIT

luit is probably packaged into X11 in the Oracle LInux repositories and I don't need all of X11

I downloaded the source for luit from https://invisible-island.net/luit/, compiled it and used that as follows.

```
sudo yum install gcc
wget https://invisible-island.net/datafiles/release/luit.tar.gz
tar xvzf luit.tar.gz
cd luit*/
./configure
make
sudo make install
man luit
luit -list
cd legacy_app_dir
luit -encoding CP437 legacy_app
```

[image]